# Play console giving error using MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE?

Tags: android, kotlin, mediastore, android-external-storage

Play console is giving an error using MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE as it gives all files access to the app. But the app functionality has to get external storage permission and in android 11 and up to access files we have to use MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE what to do? One thought is to use Media store api if anyone know about this topic please help.

Comment: Which error? Should we know?

Comment: @blackapps play console rejected the app as it was using MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE to access all files and suggested to use media store api. if you know how to use media store api please help

Comment: Rejected==error? Please write a better post to begin with. After that tell why you need so much access and where exactly?

Comment: @blackapps will this permission be accepted by my file sharing app like xender?

Comment: @HasIEIus, i see no reason that your app should not accept it.

Answer (score 0):

how I work around this is to suppress the issue this is allowable and i use this on an app in Play Store

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
```

it could be your same issue but when I suppress it with ignore I have no issue

Answer (score 0):

if just want to access videos and images in indroid 11 and higher , instead of using MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE use below permissions: